# Is it bad practice to have validation of an instance variable depend on another instance variable?

Tags: java

Is it bad to have one variable depend on the state of another variable?

For example, I have a class `Date` which has the attributes `day`, `month`, and `year`. Month and year can be independently validated in their respective setters, but `day` depends on `month` and / or `year` i.e. maximum number of days during a month / leap year. My approach is to ensure that my constructor requires all three fields, and it will call the setter for `day` after `month` and `year`.

Is a state dependency like this discouraged? My class is not immutable, so I need some sort of validation, and I want to encapsulate the validation in the class itself rather than do it externally.

Below is my current code :

```java
   class Date {
      private int day;
      private int month;
      private int year;

      public String toString() {
         return String.format("%02d/%02d/%04d", month, day, year);
      }

      public int getMonth() {
         return month;
      }

      public void setMonth(int month) {
         // Check if month is valid
         if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
               String.format("%02d is not a valid month", month)
               );
         } else {
               this.month = month;
         }
      }

      public int getYear() {
         return year;
      }

      public void setYear(int year) {
         // Check if year is valid
         if (year < 1900 || year > 2020) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
               String.format("%04d is not a valid year", year)
               );
         } else {
            this.year = year;
         }
      }

      public int getDay() {
         return day;
      }

      public void setDay(int day) {
         // Check if day is valid
         if (day < 1 || day > getMaxNumDaysInMonth(this.getMonth(), this.getYear())) {
            throw new IllegalAccessException(
               String.format("%02d is not a valid day", day)
            );
         } else {
            this.day = day;
         }
      }

      Date(int month, int day, int year) {
         setMonth(month);
         setYear(year);
         setDay(day);
      }

      private final int[] MAX_MONTH_DAYS = {
         0, 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31
      };

      /**
       * Gets the maximum number of days in a month
       * Depends on the month and whether the year is a leap year
       * @param month
       * @param year
       * @return
       */
      private int getMaxNumDaysInMonth(int month, int year) {

         // Check if date is valid
         if (year < 1 || month < 1 || month > 12) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
               String.format("%04d-%02d is not a valid date", year, month)
            );
         } else {
            // Adjust February if year is a leap year
            if (month == 2) {
               if (isLeapYear(year)) {
                  return MAX_MONTH_DAYS[month];
               } else {
                  return MAX_MONTH_DAYS[month] - 1;
               }
            } else {
               return MAX_MONTH_DAYS[month];
            }
         }
      } // end getNumDaysInMonth


      /**
       * Returns true if year is a Leap year
       * Returns false otherwise
       * @param year
       * @return
       */
      private boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
         return (year % 4) == 0 && (year % 100 !=0 || year % 400 == 0);
      }
   } // end Date class
```

Comment: The way you are doing it, I would say "no it's not bad practice."  If you for example also had a `java.util.Date` instance field in the class, then it would be redundant and probably not a great idea.

Comment: Does your class have to be mutable?  (Making your own date classes for real applications is almost always a bad idea; strongly prefer `java.time` types over literally anything else.)

Comment: Yeah it’s just for a homework assignment. I definitely wouldn’t use my own Date class in production. This just got me curious about designs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argument validation is always a great idea, there are actually classes dedicated to do this kind of thing for you as well to make it even easier.

[Preconditions](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html?is-external=true)

```java
      public void setMonth(int month) {
         Preconditions.checkArgument(month >= 1 && month <= 12, String.format("%s is not a valid month.", month)); 
         this.month = month.
      }
```

**On an unrelated note regarding mutability**

If you want this class to be immutable but still allow for methods like setMonth you can always make the fields final and return a new Date with the new month for example.

```java
class Date {

    private final int month;

    private final int day;

    private final int year;

    // constructor

    public Date setMonth(int month) {
        // check argument is valid
        return new Date(day, month, year);
    }
}
```

```java
Date date = new Date(2020, 3, 7);

date = date.setMonth(4);
```

**Did you know this has already been done?**

Do you need to create a class that manages Date? This already exists, and has been vastly improved in the last few years.

```java
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();

        localDate = localDate.withMonth(4).withDayOfMonth(8).withYear(2021);

        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();

        localDateTime = localDateTime.withHour(9).withMinute(45).withSecond(30).withDayOfMonth(8);

        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now();

        zonedDateTime = zonedDateTime.withZoneSameLocal(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
```

Comment: Yup! My assignment specifically forbids the usage of built-in or third-party classes. I definitely wouldn’t make my own Date class IRL, but this example bring up an interesting question about validation of interrelated instance variables. If I wanted to have a setter for day, should I have that setter validate against month and year? If that’s the case, month and year would need to be set before day always. Eg if I first set the year to 2020 then I could set the month to Feb and day to 29 since it is a leap year. I can’t set day =29 if month is Feb and year is 2019

Comment: Well when you change the day, you need to check if the day is within the range of days for the current month since some months have more days the others. One way around this would be to use a Builder pattern for the Date class and require the Year and Month to be set before the day.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Jason consider creating an immutable class. Right now your implementation is not safe. Users can break your class invariant by using different 'set' methods on already existing instance. For example, create a date of January, 31. Then set month to February. Because you only check for valid month there the resulting date will be 31 of February. Same for 29 Feb 2020 and change year to 2019.

If your class is immutable then you just need to place all validity checks inside a constructor and don't need to worry about preserving the class invariants in all 'set' methods.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. Here's my thought: your object really only has one state variable: a date. That you must set that state variable by providing three separate numbers is a detail of your implementation.

Your validation should reject any attempt to set the state variable to some bogus value.

If you had a class with more than one state variable, it would be helpful to your users to validate them independently. But not for a date.

Comment: That’s a fair point, though I’m unfortunately stuck with this example in this assignment (a custom Date class with 3 instance variables). In general, is it discouraged to manage an individual instance variable which has dependencies on other instance variables? It seems like it could be a design flaw in my assignment, a design flaw in my logic, or I’m completely overthinking it.